# When can I use a boolean DataArray for indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, python-xarray

I'm using an [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) `DataArray` object for boolean indexing.  It works… sometimes.  In the example below, it works for the large array but not for the small one:

```
In [12]: x = xarray.DataArray(numpy.arange(336*49).reshape(336,49))

In [13]: x.values[x==-1]
Out[13]: array([], dtype=int64)

In [14]: x = xarray.DataArray(numpy.arange(20*10).reshape(20, 10))

In [15]: x.values[x==-1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-9340240dc777> in <module>()
----> 1 x.values[x==-1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Is it supposed to be possible at all?  Why does it work in one case but not in the other?

(Of course, the correct adaptation would be `x.values[x.values==-1]`.  But I was quite puzzled by the observed behaviour.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in NumPy. `.values` is a NumPy array, and NumPy arrays don't seem to properly support indexing with boolean array-like objects (like an `xarray.DataArray`): https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9633